# PhoneGap application run only in one specific Android device

Tags: android, cordova, device

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap 2.9 and Eclipse Juno for Android. I run with no problems my application in my mobile phone but when I connect another mobile phone or Android tablet, Eclipse doesn't recognize them as devices so, I can't run my application.

---

I checked that those devices have not the minimum API level that is required and that the development tools and USB debugging are enabled in all of them.

---

I don't know if this has something to do with my problem, but the only device that runs the application and being recognized, is the one that I connected with Eclipse from the very first time.

Comment: I think it´s got nothing to do with eclipse, nor cordova. It´s a usb driver issue. Your devices will get recognized after reinstalling, fixing driver problems... When oyu plug them in do they appear with no problems in device administrator screen in windows??

Comment: yes yes they all appear normally in my computer. I can see their content and change, add or delete media as usual for example.

Comment: But not the debug interface... Have u followed the vendor manual in orcer to activate the debug interface of those devices? do they appear with ids after executing `adb devices`?

Comment: do you mean [those](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) instructions?

Comment: The first time I run my mobile app it works fine just by enabling the developer tools and USB debugging. I don't know why. Right now I am following the full instructions in the above link that I put.

Comment: The problem is solved. How can I Show it in stack overflow? there is no answer down my question, only comments

Comment: @marialena you can answer your own question. Try to explain in detail how the  issue was resolved, as it will help other users who visit this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[This](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)*** is the specific tutorial that I used in order to solve my problem. 
Except from that tutorial, i used ***[this](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php)*** tutorial to download and manually install the USB Driver needed. Also with this tutorial, I installed the driver in my hardware device (Android Phone). 
 I haven't test it with Android tablets but it works fine with other mobile phones than mine.